# Flex : How to truncate ComboBox label while the labelfield property is already set?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, combobox, flex4

I have one ComboBox which has a dataprovider set to `ArrayCollection`.
The `dataProvider` contains XML data.

```
<s:ComboBox id="articleComboBox" width="245" dataProvider="{_pageCollection}" labelField="title"  change="comboChange(event)"/>
```

I want a functionality that, if the the length of `itemlabel` is larger than some value(e.g 25)
the label must be truncated with the two dots(..) appended at the end.

I have implemented this in the `Change` event of ComboBox as:

```
private function comboChange(event:*):void{
   var str:String = articleComboBox.textInput.text;
   if(str.length > 25){
      str = str.slice(0, 22) + "..";
      articleComboBox.textInput.text = str;
      }
}
```

But it doesnt working. The text still displays the original "`title`" field of the `dataProvider` as a whole.

May be it's due the `labelfield` property specified in the mxml. What i am missing here??

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Please Help...

Here is the `dataProvider`(`_pageCollection`):

```
<articles>
<article id="1146270" title="new article1" page_id="3205769"></article>
<article id="1144499" title="new article2"  page_id="3205771"></article>
<article id="1082813" title="All Dressed Up And No Place To Train…" page_id="3205773"></article>
<article id="1146024" title="The NCAA Doesn" page_id="3205776"></article>
<article id="1083014" title="The Chula Vista Olympic Training Center" page_id="3205777"></article>
</articles>
```

Comment: this may help you: - str = str.slice(0, 22).concat(str.length > 22 ? "..." : ""); and call comboChange after some time interval or by using callLater(comboChange)

Comment: i.e - <s:ComboBox id="articleComboBox" width="245" dataProvider="{_pageCollection}" labelField="label"  change="{callLater(comboChange,[event])}"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a custom Skin for your ComboBox. In the skin implementation you will see:

```
<s:TextInput id="textInput" enabled.disabled="false"
                 left="0" right="18" top="0" bottom="0" 
                 skinClass="spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxTextInputSkin"/>
```

This is the actual TextInput you need. You can play with it or modify `spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxTextInputSkin` it is using.

For example, add `change` handler to react when a user changes it's content so you could reformat the string.

Comment: @Max.. Thanks for answering But I have to do this without making changes in the skin class

Comment: @FlexCoder Why is that? Looks like the most sensible way to go to me. Otherwise you'd just be recreating functionality that already exists.

Comment: @RIAStar.. thats because there is only one skin class used for all comboboxes in whole application. And if I make change that skin.. wouldn't it reflect in the other Comboboxes too..??

Comment: No, you can assign skin classes individually using skinClass property. Like in the example I provided above.

Comment: @MaxGolovanchuk .. okay that was a new thing I learned here today. your soluton also works fine.. thanks